# Singular values of $X+iY$ where $X$ and $Y$ are Hermitian

Tags: matrices, sp.spectral-theory

Lets have two Hermitian $n\times n$ matrices $X$ and $Y$.

Are there any known properties of the singular values of
$$Z = X + i Y.$$

I am the most interested in bounding from above a few first singular values of $Z$ by the eigenvalues of $X$ and $Y$. And sth that is stronger than:

$$\sum_{i=1}^k \sigma_i^2(Z)\leq \sum_{i=1}^k \left( \lambda_i^2(X)+\lambda_i^2(Y)+\lambda_i(i[X,Y]) \right)$$
for $1\leq k \leq n$ and (singular/eigen)values sorted in the decreasing order.

Comment: The problem about eigenvalues of sums of Hermitian matrices was solved by Alexander Klyachko, in "Stable bundles, representation theory and Hermitian operators", Selecta Math. 4 (1998), no. 3, 419-445. See also Fulton's survey article "Eigenvalues, invariant factors, highest weights, and Schubert calculus" http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/9908.5012



Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31475/singular-values-of-matrix-sums , although your case is more special than this one.

Comment: @Misha here's an updated link for that paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9908012

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some results in this direction that you might find useful are listed below.

> **Theorem** (Bhatia and Kittaneh). Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be as in the question above. Then,
>   \begin{equation*}
> \| (X^2+Y^2)^{1/2} \|_p \le \|Z\|_p \le 2^{1/2-1/p}\| (X^2+Y^2)^{1/2} \|_p,
> \end{equation*}
>   where $2 \le p \le \infty$, and $\|\cdot\|_p$ denotes the Schatten-$p$ norm. The inequality above gets reversed for $1\le p \le 2$. Also, these inequalities are sharp.

Even more directly relevant is the following theorem that discusses majorization of singular values of $X+Y$ by those of $Z$.

> **Theorem** (Bhatia and Kittaneh). Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be as in the question. Then
>   \begin{equation*}
> \sigma(X+Y)\quad \prec_w\quad \sqrt{2}\sigma(Z)
> \end{equation*}
>   If $X$ is psd, then the above weak majorization can be replaced by *weak log-majorization*, that is,
>   \begin{equation*}
> \prod_{j=1}^k \sigma_j(X+Y) \le \prod_{j=1}^k\sqrt{2}\sigma_j(Z).
> \end{equation*}
>   Finally, if both $X$ and $Y$ are psd, then we have even stronger inequalities:
>   \begin{equation*}
>   \sigma_j(X+Y) \le \sqrt{2}\sigma_j(Z)\quad 1 \le j \le n.
> \end{equation*}

Bhatia and Kittaneh also discuss some applications of the above theorem to commutator inequalities.

**References**

1. R. Bhatia and F. Kittaneh. "The singular values of $A+B$ and $A+iB$." *Linear Algebra and its Applications*, 431(2009), pp. 1502-1508.
2. R. Bhatia and F. Kittaneh. "Cartesian decompositions and Schatten norms." *Linear Algebra and its Applications*, 318(2000), pp. 109--116.