# Singular Values of Linearly Combined Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a question related with singular values of matrix sums.

Let's assume I have matrices $A$, $B$, and $D$ (positive, semi-definite) where $D = A + B$. For singular values of $D$, I know that

$$
λ(D) \le ∑λ(A)+∑λ(B).
$$

However, if I want to calculate the singular values of $D = A + cB$, where $c$ is a constant (real number) other than just $1$, does the assumption above still hold?

Thus, can I assume that for the singular values of $D = A + cB$ the following holds

$$
∑λ(D) \le ∑λ(A) + c∑λ(B).
$$

Comment: Could you define $\lambda(D)$ and possibly check whether the following MO posts http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4224/eigenvalues-of-matrix-sums and its follow-up http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31475/singular-values-of-matrix-sums may help prove or disprove your inequalities?

Comment: This is true; it's the triangle inequality for the trace norm.

Comment: (assuming of course $c \ge 0$)

Comment: So, it won't be true for $c < 0$ @RobertIsrael? Because, I may also use negative real numbers.

Comment: If $A$, $B$ **and** $A + c B$ are all positive semidefinite, the singular values are just the eigenvalues and their sum is the trace.  Then of course $\sum \lambda(A+cB) = \sum \lambda(A) + c \sum \lambda(B)$.  You only need an inequality when $A+cB$ might not be positive semidefinite, and that inequality will require $c \ge 0$.