# Commuting hermitian matrices

Tags: matrices

Let $A$, $B$ be $n\times n$ hermitian matrices. Denote by $(\alpha_i)$, $(\beta_i)$, $(\gamma_i)$  the eigenvalues of $A$, $B$, and $A+B$.  Assume that there exists permutations $\sigma$, $\tau \in \frak S_n$ so that 
$$\gamma_i = \alpha_{\sigma(i)} + \beta_{\tau(i)}$$ for all $1\le i \le n$. Does this imply that $A$, $B$ commute?

Comment: No necessarily, Let  A and B be two  big size nilpotent matrices which are strictly upper triangle

Comment: I am sorry I did not pay attention to "hermitian"

Comment: may be  a related post  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34252/eigenvalues-of-ab-where-a-is-symmetric-positive-definite-and-b-is-diagonal

Comment: @Dennis Serre: I don't know the exact statement of that theorem. Besides, I guess it describes the possibilities for the spectrum of the sum. Not sure it tells when  some ( extreme?) cases occur.

Comment: this does not look extreme

Comment: Please spell my name with one N only: Denis.

Comment: @DenisSerre You might wish to correct the spelling of Allen Knutson's last name :)

Answer (score 10):

The answer is negative. Let $C$ and $D$ be two noncommuting $n\times n$ hermitian matrices, and define the block matrices
  $$ A=C\oplus (C+D)\oplus 0_n,\ \ \ B=D\oplus(-C)\oplus 0_n, $$
where $0_n$ is the $n\times n$ matrix of all 0's.

Answer (score 8):

This question was the topic of [Commutativity and spectra of Hermitian matrices,](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0024379594903999/1-s2.0-0024379594903999-main.pdf?_tid=cc2d5440-a939-11e7-85b4-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1507145316_fe7f0eaebb9a73fbdd4de96ddab04554) by Wasin So (1994).

The statement is negative in general: Richard Stanley's counterexample has size $n\geq 6$, a counterexample for $n=3$ is
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\
0&6-\sqrt 2&2\\
0&2&4+2\sqrt 2
\end{pmatrix},\;\;B=\begin{pmatrix}
4&0&0\\
0&-4&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix},$$

There are special cases when the statement holds:

If $\gamma_i = \alpha_{\sigma(i)} + \beta_{\tau(i)}$ for a permutation $\sigma(i)$ and $\tau(i)$ of the eigenvalues $\alpha_i,\beta_i,\gamma_i$ in non-increasing order, then the $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices $A,B$ commute if either

- $n=2$
- rank $A=1$
- $\sigma(i)=i$ for all $i$ (identity permutation)
- $\sigma(i)=n+1-i$ for all $i$ (reverse permutation)