# Eigenvalues of $A^2+B^2$ from those of $A$, $B$ and $A+B$

Tags: linear-algebra

This question comes from a colleague working in econometrics. $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ real symmetric matrices. If we know the eigenvalues of $A$, $B$ and $A+B$, what meaningful information can we obtain about the eigenvalues of $A^2+B^2$?

I have read this [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4224/eigenvalues-of-matrix-sums), but here we have the extra information of the eigenvalues of $A+B$.

Comment: We may get many inequalities for them, but i am afraid that to describe the complete set of inequalities is rather hopeless. But maybe for applications in econometrics we do need them all? If so, the question should be specified...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial answer, that could evolve in a few hours.

If  $\theta+\nu>0$, then you have
$$A^2+B^2\ge(1-\theta)A^2+(1-\nu)B^2+\frac{\theta\nu}{\theta+\nu}(A+B)^2.$$
With Horn's inequalities, you deduce inequalities for the eigenvalues of $A^2+B^2$ in terms of those of $A^2$, $B^2$ and $(A+B)^2$. The latter are the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$, $B$ and $A+B$.

For instance, using Weyl's inequality
$$\lambda_k(F+G)\ge\lambda_i(F)+\lambda_j(G),\qquad k+1=i+j,$$
we obtain
$$\lambda_m(A^2+B^2)\ge\lambda_i((1-\theta)A^2)+\lambda_j((1-\nu)B^2)+\lambda_k\left(\frac{\theta\nu}{\theta+\nu}(A+B)^2\right),\qquad m+2=i+j+k.$$

Comment: @Denis I have voted your answer, but I am still interested in any evolution.

Comment: also note that if $A, B \ge 0$, then a result of Ando and Zhan says that $\lambda(A^r+B^r) \preceq_w \lambda( (A+B)^r)$ for $r\ge 1$ (weak majorization).