# Spectral Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be an undirected graph, then
Laplacian Matrix(L(G)) = Degree Matrix (D(G)) - Adjacency Matrix (A(G)).
What is the relationship between laplacian and adjacency spectrum of undirected graphs?

Comment: What do you already know about this? From what background are you coming at the problem? This will help potential answerers.

Comment: We already have an adjacency spectrum then what is the advantage of laplacian spectrum over adjacency spectrum and as these two matrices are related, there must exist some relationship between their spectra right?

Comment: "there must exist some relationship between their spectra right?" Well, why do you think there is a relation between the spectra of the sum of two matrices and the spectra of the individual matrices? (Some things can be said for Hermitian matrices, but they are probably harder and deeper and less precise than what you seem to be hoping for.)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that, if your graph is not regular, there is no relation. The effect on the eigenvalues of adding a diagonal matrix is the same as adding an arbitary symmetric matrix.

Comment: I think this answer is not quite correct: there obviously is a relation, as the two matrices determine each other, just no one knows how to describe it :)

Comment: Your comment is correct for the matrices, but you asked about the _spectrum_.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't ask. So, can you **prove** that there's no relation whatsoever? Meaning, that every pair of spectra can be realized by the two matrices of the same graph?

Comment: I offered only the "the short answer". For example, if the graph has one vertex of degree $k$ and the rest have degree $\ell$, you can derive an interlacing result. But I have never seen anyone find a useful connection between the two spectra.

Comment: So there is no proper relation between these two spectra? @ChrisGodsil

Comment: None is known in general.

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev presumably there are some constraints due to the Horn inequalities http://mathoverflow.net/questions/4224/eigenvalues-of-matrix-sums but that doesn't mean they are useful or better than "trivial constraints"