# Name for matrices with vanishing row and column sums

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

> **Question:**
>
> is there a special name for matrices whose rows and columns sum to zero?

I actually need information about those matrices and thus **a keyword for online search**.

**Edit:**
as there apparently is no name for those kind of matrices, I would like to suggest ,*"Vibration Matrices*" for discussion, because [vibrating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibration) membranes exhibit an analogous property with respect to the unexcited state as the zero-level.

**Further edit:**
[Laplacian Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) are integer valued examples of diagonally dominant matrices with vanishing row- and column sums.

Comment: This question looks relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293024/properties-of-zero-line-sum-matrices

Comment: @Spencer, maybe you noticed that that question was posted by the user who has posted this one.

Comment: Oh, I did not. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: That was not on intent, I had forgotten about my earlier question, but still I would appreciate a keyword for those kind of matrices or, if there isn't one in use, suggestions for such a name.

Comment: Note that if $S$ is [doubly-stochastic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_stochastic_matrix), then $S-I$ is  your matrix. Maybe useful?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen true, but not all of 'my' matrices are of that structure because $|a_{ij}|\le 1$ for doubly stochastic matrices, whereas no such restriction exists for 'my' matrices. Of course every zero linesum matrix can be scaled to satisfy $\max(|a_{ij})|\in \lbrace 0,1\rbrace$

Comment: I know $e$-matrices for constant raw sum.

Comment: @ToniMhax could you please provide further information about where I can find that name mentioned?

Comment: Yes i saw it here 
  http://bkms.kms.or.kr/submission/Source/Download.php?FileDir=/201711/171187&FileName=B170964AOP.pdf

Comment: @ToniMhax in definition 1.4 of the article an $e-matrix$ is defined as a matrix for which $e$ (the all ones vector) is an eigenvector, so it seems to me that the term $e-matrix$ isn't used for constant row-sum matrices.