# Frobenius inner product of a zero line-sum matrix and a doubly stochastic matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, matrices, inequalities

Let $A$, $B$ be two $n\times n$ real matrices.

Let $A$ be a zero line-sum matrix where each row sum and each column sum equals zero, i.e., $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{ij}=0 $$ (it seems there is no name for such matrix, see [Name for matrices with vanishing row and column sums](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336925/name-for-matrices-with-vanishing-row-and-column-sums?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Let $B$ be a matrix where every entry is non-negative and each row sum and each column sum equals 1, i.e.,
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_{ij}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}b_{ij}=1, b_{ij}\geq 0 $$ ($B$ is a doubly stochastic matrix).

An index set $S\subset[n]\times[n]$ is a permutation set if $S$ has $n$ elements and if for every $(i,j),(i'j')\in S$, $(i,j)\neq(i',j')$ then $i\neq i;$ and $j\neq j'$.

Now suppose there exists a permutation set $S$ such that $a_{ij}\geq 0$ for every  $(i,j)\in S$, $a_{ij}\leq 0$ for every $(i,j)\notin S$ and  $\sum_{(i,j)\in S} b_{ij}\geq \sum_{(i,j)\in S'} b_{ij}$ for every permuation set $S'$. Is it true that $\langle A,B\rangle_F\geq 0$?

Note this is obviously true if $B$ is a permutation matrix or if $b_{ij}=1/n$ for every $(i,j)$. These seems like the two extreme cases. But how to prove it in general?

Comment: A small correction: $B$ is called a *doubly stochastic matrix*, not a Birkhoff polytope. The *Birkhoff polytope* is the set of all doubly stochastic matrices (in fixed dimension).

Comment: @JochenGlueck Thanks! I miswrote it because I was thinking about minimizing $\langle A,B\rangle_F$ over a Birkhoff polytope.

Comment: Going beyond your two examples, a computer might be of help finding potential counterexamples here. Data enters the problem in a very combinatorial way, and it's hard to get an intuition for why the statement should be true in general. So my 2 cents would be to try to finding some genuine counterexamples (e.g using a computer), and only in case of failure to find such, should you have more confidence in the claim, and try proving it.

Comment: @dohmatob Thanks for your advice! I used Sage to try the $3 \times3$ case and I found that the Birkhoff polytope, with the additional property I required on $B$ (I let $S=\{(i,i)\}$), has 24 vertices, which is indeed hard to analyze. I have changed the question to a weaker one which I believe is true.