# Projecting a symmetric matrix onto the space of linear operators with a particular eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, oc.optimization-and-control, eigenvalues

Specifically, I am interested in the case where one eigenvalue is exactly $0$.  Given an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix, I would like to find the closest $n\times n$ symmetric matrix that has one eigenvalue that is equal to $0$.

Although the $n\times n$ matrices form a [Hilbert space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space), the set of symmetric matrices with a zero eigenvalue is probably not convex, because the eigenvalues of a sum of two matrices [has a complex relationship](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/4224/eigenvalues-of-matrix-sums) with the original matrices.  Thus, the [classic projection theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_projection_theorem) does not guarantee a unique solution.  However, I only need *a* solution.  Since the eigenvalues of a matrix are continuous in the entries, the set of $n\times n$ matrices with a zero eigenvalue should be closed, and so the set of solutions shouldn't be totally insane.

In any case, how can I find the closest $n\times n$ symmetric matrix(es) with a zero eigenvalue to an arbitrary given $n\times n$ symmetric matrix?

Comment: How do you define "closest"?

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt with whatever arbitrary metric on matrices.  A handful can be gotten from the various [matrix norms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm).  For context, I am using this in a constrained optimization problem, so I perturb my original matrix a bit and it no longer has a zero eigenvalue, I want to get it back to having a zero eigenvalue, but not be too far away from where I started.  If a particularly convenient solution happens to correspond to a particular metric, then that's the correct metric.  :)

Comment: Ah, then it seems the answer that has already been given below is just the thing - great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any (real) symmetric matrix may be diagonalised by an orthogonal matrix. So let your matrix be $A$ and let $O$ be an orthogonal matrix such that $D=OAO^{-1}$ is diagonal. Note that the transformation $A\mapsto OAO^{-1}$ is distance preserving. Now get $D'$ by replacing whichever diagonal entry of $D$ has least absolute value, and let $A'=O^{-1}D'O$.

([Nathaniel Johnston](https://mathoverflow.net/users/11236/nathaniel-johnston)'s [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/343072/projecting-a-symmetric-matrix-onto-the-space-of-linear-operators-with-a-particul/343077?noredirect=1#comment857707_343077) let me find the related paper "[Low-Rank Positive Approximants of Symmetric Matrices](https://file.scirp.org/pdf/ALAMT_2014092513143053.pdf)" by Achiya Dax.)

Comment: I'll just note (for the sake of adding Google-able terms) that this is essentially the [Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation) restricted to symmetric matrices.